# Some troubles while converting authors id to User model

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

My Post model have list of authors id

```
class Post(Document):
   authors_id = ListField(IntField(required=True), required=True)
```

But sometime I need to use default Django *User* class. How most rapidly I can do it?

(I'm using sqlite for users and sessions and MongoDB (mongoengine ODM) for other. Don't ask why:))

I was tried to write it:

```
def get_authors(self):
    authors = list()
    for i in self.authors_id:
        authors.append(get_user(IntField.to_python(self.authors_id[i])))
    return authors
```

...and it raises 'list index out of range' exception. (authors id not empty, really). What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the to_python method but since you are looping through the authors_id, there is no need to do

```
authors.append(get_user(IntField.to_python(self.authors_id[i])))
```

You should be good with

```
authors.append(get_user(IntField.to_python(i)))
```

Comment: .. and unbound method to_python() must be called with IntField instance as first argument (got int instance instead) :) – just so 19 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
IntField.to_python(self.authors_id[i]))
```

I think you just need to do:

```
IntField.to_python(i)
```

In Python the 'for i in some_list' construction gives you elements of the list, not integer indexes.

Comment: .. and `unbound method to_python() must be called with IntField instance as first argument (got int instance instead)` 
:)

Answer (score 0):

You said that you were getting this error:

```
and unbound method to_python() must be called with IntField instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

I got a similar error from MongoEngine.  In my case the problem was that I defined the field like this:

```
foo_id = IntField
```

The correct way to define it is:

```
foo_id = IntField()
```

When I added the parenthesis, the problem went away.